# Access previous element in a python list

Tags: python, list, loops, range

This looks so simple, I don't see why it doesn't work.

This code accesses the previous element in the list with `[i-1]`:

```
# I found this on Stack Overflow and it works
l=[1,2,3]
for i,item in enumerate(l):
    if item==2:
        get_previous=l[i-1]
        print "get_previous = " + str(get_previous)
```

This does not access the previous list element even though it exists because it is printed out as `line1[0]`.

```
# What happens to $1,000 if you earn 1,2,3% interest for 30 years?
initial_amount = 1000.00
ratio1 = 1.01
ratio2 = 1.02
ratio3 = 1.03
line1 = []
line2 = []
line3 = []
line1.append(initial_amount)
line2.append(initial_amount)
line3.append(initial_amount)
print "line1[0] = " + str(line1[0])
for index in range(0, 30):
    print "index outside of if = " + str(index)
    if(index > 0):
        print "index inside if = " + str(index)
        line1[index] = line1[index-1] * ratio1
        line2[index] = line2[index-1] * ratio2
        line3[index] = line3[index-1] * ratio3
```

The output is:

```
get_previous = 1
line1[0] = 1000.0
index outside of if = 0
index outside of if = 1
index inside if = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
    line1[index] = line1[index-1] * ratio1
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: It fails because `list[index]` doesn't exist the first time through.  You need to append new data to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `line1.append(..)` as:

```
line1.append(line1[index-1] * ratio1)
line2.append(line2[index-1] * ratio2)
line3.append(line3[index-1] * ratio3)
```

Because you are trying to *update value* at 1th index which is not currently present in list (i.e length of list `line1` is 1). In order to  *insert the value* at last, python has `list.append(..)` method.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked.  I thought it failed because of the reference to [index-1] but it was failing because of the [index] reference.  I was taking for granted that it would create the [index] element in the list.  I  guess that happens in perl and not Python.

Comment: @R.Wayne It think that it should work in the languages where you define the size of the list while creating the array object. But in Python (like some of the other languages), since the you don't define the size and size is increased dynamically - it won't work. And Perl must be falling in former category (PS: never used Perl)